# core data and iCloud

Tags: swift, core-data, icloud

recently I have been trying to setup core iCloud syncing with already set up core data within my app.

I've tried to make use of some interesting links like:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/UsingCoreDataWithiCloudPG/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013491-CH3-SW8

and

https://www.objc.io/issues/10-syncing-data/icloud-core-data/

but with no real outcome.

I have created a helper class:
`import Foundation
import CoreData

class CloudHelper{

```
// Singleton
static let sharedInstance = CloudHelper()

let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

// MARK: Public functions    
// MARK: Notification Observers
func registerForiCloudNotifications(){
    let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()

    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: Selector("storesWillChange:"), name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification, object: appDelegate.persistentStoreCoordinator)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: Selector("storesDidChange:"), name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification, object: appDelegate.persistentStoreCoordinator)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: Selector("persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges"), name: NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification, object: appDelegate.persistentStoreCoordinator)
}

// MARK: iCloud Support

private func iCloudPersistentStoreOptions() -> [String : String]{
    return [NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey: "myAppStore"]
}

private func persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges(changeNotification: NSNotification){
    let context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    context?.performBlock({ () -> Void in
        context?.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(changeNotification)
    })
}

private func storesWillChange(notification: NSNotification){
    let context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    context.performBlockAndWait({ () -> Void in
        let error: NSError
        if  context.hasChanges{
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch let error1 as NSError {
                error = error1
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        context.reset()
    })

    // Refresh UI
}

private func storesDidChange(notification: NSNotification){
    // Refresh UI
}
```

}
`

Is this it? Because when I run the app and it makes some changes in the core data, I don't see the changes on my other device even if I re run the app.... Did I forget something?

Comment: Since `iCloudPersistentStoreOptions()` is private, where do you pass this – crucial and  required – option to the persistent store?

Comment: Actually I have no idea where to use it ...

Comment: You have to pass it when/where the variable `persistentStoreCoordinator` is created lazily right before the store is added. Actually it's well described in the documentation (your first link)

Comment: I have just realized I need to put it in appDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator method. But is that it?

Comment: Yes, that's it. And make sure that the notifications are available

Comment: Its working! Thanks for opening my eyes!